# If you cancel a subversion commit, are the so-far sent files committed?

Tags: svn, source-control

On a subversion repo, I just added 2 GB (100 files) to my local copy, and committed.

FTR this is using the popular Versions.app as a client - the repo is an ordinary xp-dev svn repo.

It's now 1/2 way through and has uploaded half the files to the subversion repo (let's say 55 of the files about 1gb total.)

In fact:

if I hit "cancel" at this point, will those 55 files be committed?  Will it make a commit (say, commit #174 with 55 new files)?  Or in fact, will it just 'completely waste' that 1gb of upload?

what's the facts on that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVN commits are [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit):  the commit happens either completely or not at all.  If you cancel the commit process, the data uploaded so far will be discarded and no new revision will be created.